# If $f=u+iv:D\to \Bbb C$ is analytic on a domain D, is then the curves $u(x,y)=c_1$ and $v(x,y)=c_2$ intersect orthogonally?

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f=u+iv:D\to \Bbb C$ is analytic on a domain D (an open connected subset of $\Bbb C$), is then the curves $u(x,y)=c_1$ and $v(x,y)=c_2$ intersect orthogonally, for any constants $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: What do the Cauchy-Riemann equations have to do with the question?

Comment: Since $\nabla u\cdot \nabla v=0$, the result follows by using the fact that a curve and its gradient are perpendicular. I wanted to know did I miss any conditions so that the result fails to hold, in particular any restrictions on the constants or anything else?

Comment: ... if they intersect at all

Comment: I don't know how to hint at it well without saying it, so: consider $f'(z) = 0$.

Comment: Have a look at $f(z)=z^2$ and $c_1=c_2=0$. In what angles do your curves intersect and are they curves in the first place?

Comment: $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v=2xy$. $u=0$ and $v=0$ represents the the pair of straight lines $y=\pm x$ and the coordinate axes respectively and the intersect at the origin.